# Как в supervisor определить cwd

Tags: linux, supervisor

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
[program:lavalink]
command=java -jar /APP/lavalink/Lavalink.jar # cwd должен быть .../lavalink
[program:bot]
command=poetry run python /APP/my-bot/app/main.py # cwd должен быть .../my-app
```

Comment: `directory=/lavalink` не работает для вас?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Параметр directory. Лучше указать полный путь.

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings